# Searching a range of events in a time graph

Tags: graph, neo4j

I'm trying to implement the graph from this blog post: http://blog.neo4j.org/2012/02/modeling-multilevel-index-in-neoj4.html

Inside the blogpost is a schematic of the graph and a query on how to find a range of events. However in my use case i don't have a set consecutive days. So for example the current state of the graph could be that i have day nodes from 12-7-2013 (12 july 2013) to 12-8-2013 (12 august 2013). Then when adding an event on 12-7-2014 i'm missing all the inbetween days for a whole year!

First problem is if i start to write queries that generate those days it might become very slow (application needs to be responsive). Second problem is i end up with days on which no event could be taken place, and so have unneeded data in my database.

So my question is: How can i get a range of events without using the NEXT relation between days?

Comment: and why is it a problem to link from 12-8-2013 to 12-7-2014 using the NEXT relationship, if there's nothing in between?

Comment: If i do that then when i enter a new day in between 1-1-2014, i would have the following relationships: 12-8-2013 -[:NEXT]-> 12-7-2014, 12-8-2013 -[:NEXT]-> 1-1-2014, 1-1-2014 -[:NEXT]-> 12-7-2014. That's 3 relationships now where i only need one. Over time this will accumulate a lot of unncessary relationships, so i would have to perform regular cleanup queries which is less then ideal.

Comment: I think you should clean it up as soon as it happens! That's how a tree index works. You rarely know the values of the leaves up front (as in the case of Peter's tree in the blog post). So when a new date is inserted, you should re-link the NEXT relationships accordingly - not a big job.

Comment: It depends on how expensive the queries are to find the previous and next day (which are located on an arbitrary position). If it's a lookup on all the days possible then this tree doesn't help that much anymore in performance (still fast on reading, but much? slower on writing). If i'm wrong in my assumption you could post your answer with queries and i can accept it if it's good.

Comment: Actually, it is not an arbitrary position, you'll find it in O(log(n)) time (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree). I won't be able to code it up for you right now but I'm planning to add this exact kind of capability to my Neo4j "GraphAware" framework, but it won't be this week, unfortunately. It really depends, whether you want to build a full-blown B-tree, or if you have years and months fixed (1 node for each)... By the way, I also suggest connecting the year and month nodes with NEXT relationships, will speed up the lookups... I'll let you know when I've built it, if it's not too late.

Comment: I'm using the REST interface with a library. I have 1 node per 1 year, 1 per 1 month, 1 per one day. But i don't have all of them (some days could be missing). I'm doing a property search on the relation now to find the range that i need. Would be interesting to compare your solution. I will check back.